# precedence of && and || operators in java

Tags: java, operator-keyword

```
    Postfix operators [] . (parameters) expression++ expression--
Unary prefix operators ++expression --expression +expression -expression ~ !
Unary prefix creation and cast new (type)
Multiplicative * / %
Additive + -
Shift << >> >>>
Relational < <= > >= instanceof
Equality == !=
Bitwise/logical AND &
Bitwise/logical XOR ^
Bitwise/logical OR |
Conditional AND &&    //here
Conditional OR ||     //here   
Conditional ?:
Assignment = += -= *= /= %= <<= >>= >>>= &= ^= |=
```

This are the operator precedence s published in kalid A Mughal & Rasmussen book

according to this book `&&` has higher precedence than `||` but the following code

```
  if(true&&false||true)
{
    System.out.println("yes");
}
```

this code prints `"yes"`. means first executing `"||"`

is this book wrong? or my interpretation wrong.

Comment: That's not a valid test.  (true && false) == false.  false || true == true.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your interpretation is wrong. Since `&&` has higher precedence the order of evaluation is

```
(true && false) || true
```

which is

```
false || true -> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is off.  If we follow the book, your if-statement can be re-written and maintain the same meaning

```
if( (true && false) || true)
```

Now it is very easy to see that this does in fact evaluate to true, and therefore print out "yes".

Answer (score 0):

1. `true && false` => `false`
2. `false || true` => `true`

Thus there is no issue as the and statement is executing first then the or statement. The expected result of the code is `yes`.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is wrong

`true && false -> false`

`false || true -> true`

It is expected to print "yes"

Answer (score 0):

`if(true && false || true)` ==> `if(false || true)` ==> `if(true)`.

---

**AND Truth Table:**

```
 F & F = F
 T & F = F
 F & T = F
 T & T = T
```

**OR Truth Table:**

```
 F | F = F
 T | F = T
 F | T = T
 T | T = T
```

Answer (score 0):

look carefully, as these are **short-circuit** AND and OR

So the first part :

```
 true&&false // evaluates to false
```

Then you have :

```
 false || true
```

the first part is false, BUT the second part could be true (and in fact it is), thus it moves to check the second part, sees that it's true, thus returns true

Answer (score 0):

If you change your representation you can see it much clearer, for example:

```
if(true || true && false) {
    System.out.println("yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("no");
}
```

If `&&` takes precedence you have `( true || (true && false) )` this will be true so will print "yes".

If `||` takes precence you will have `( (true || true) && false)` this will be false and will print out "no.

If you run the above code you will see that the result is "yes" and therefore `&&` has precendence.

Answer (score 0):

The && is evaluated first... but one side of the "or" || is true, so the overall expression evaluates to "true"

```
if(true&&false||true)
{
    System.out.println("yes");
}
```